# Flexible, non-linear folder structure

Tags: stata, directory-structure

We do research in Stata and are a changing team of several researchers. In the current project, we have data from multiple waves, for which I have created different do-files to clean raw data, and to merge the waves. I put all this in a folder, such that the folder "Data" contains the sub-folders "Wave1", "Wave2", etc. and each of these contains several folders for data (e.g., raw data, clean data, etc.).

Each wave is organised in the same way. Since the folder structure is linear, I can have a master do-file in "Data" that flexibly reads out the computers directory (cd "`c(pwd)'/"), so that for all calls of a subsequent do-file I just add the sub-folder (e.g. use "Wave 1/Raw data/x.dta"). That way, I avoid people on the team changing directories every time they use the files on their machines.

If I have a few projects such that my folder "Data" is only in one of them: How can I tell my analysis do-file in folder "Project2" that the master do-file is in a sub-folder of its sibling "Project1" (e.g."Project1/Data/") without it knowing the computer's root directory (to make it flexible on all our computers)?

I tried the simple solution, working with `cd ../`, but:

```
cd "`c(pwd)'/"
cd ../
do "Project1/Data/y.do"
```

does not help since when I run the do-file multiple times, it goes up the directory path because it seems to remember the path it first read in and executes `cd ../` on it every time. Hence, at the first run everything works, at the second run it ends up one folder higher in the hierarchy, etc.

Is there a way to delete the directory memory at the beginning of the do-file? Or any other way? I couldn't find anything. Yet, it seems so simple.

Answer (score 2):

I use [`fastcd`](https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s429301.html) to address this issue and find that it's easier than using different locals/globals on each computer.

Type `ssc install fastcd` in Stata to install the `fastcd` package, then type `help fastcd`. The package is named `fastcd`, but the actual user-written program is named `c`.

On each computer, a user should change the working directory to the project root directory (the parent directory of `Project1`, `Project2`, etc.). Then they should give that directory a consistent name.

```
* Change the working directory to
* the project root directory.
cd ...
* Use -c cur- to give the directory a name.
c cur myproject
* Now you can use -c- to return to that directory at
* any time.
c myproject
* To change the working directory to Project1:
c myproject
cd Project1
```

Now all your do-files can use `c` rather than `cd`. The user just has to associate the directory with the `fastcd` code once, and that should be all the configuration required.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Matthew! I will check this out right away. If you don't mind me asking already, what is the exact advantage for you over using globals across multiple do-files in the same fashion?

Comment: For anyone who reads this later: fastcd did not work for me right away. I needed to manually create the directory.txt file in my "ado/personal" folder. Then it works just fine.

Comment: Where are you thinking of defining the globals? Personally, I've never found a great place to set globals that vary between computers, and the main thing that seems to vary is directories, which `fastcd` can handle. I also like that with `fastcd`, if a new user joins the project, that won't require any changes to the codebase.

Comment: I outsourced a "dir" do-file that reads in the root (as decribed) and shoves it into a global. I then define a few other globals that incorporate the "root global" adding onto its root directory whatever sub-folder paths are useful. In whichever do-file I run, I simply call the "dir" do-file to read in the machine-specific directory structure. Now, this works well "down-stream", when the do-file that calls the "dir" do can simply go down the hierarchy of folders.

Comment: But it works less well, once I have to go up the hierarchy, for instance because I am in a different project folder (as described). In that case, if I use cd ../, I can use the do-file only once, and have to close it before using it again - otherwise its root directory will be one level higher in the hierarchy of folders each time I run the do. Hope that is clear! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a fancy answer for this, but maybe a utilitarian one. It would be possible to have a line at the top of your do file like this:

```
local home "C:\folder\folder"
do "`home'\Project1\Data\y.do"
```

and each member of your team can set their own home local macro which will allow you each to define your own root directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Eric! I should have been clearer: that was our default solution before I started using cd "`c(pwd)'/" in an attempt to make it easier (and more flexible) to use. I don't want to be fancy for the sake of fanciness. If this is the only good solution that more seasoned folks than I have, I will stick with it.. ;)